# Send event from server to client to run a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I looked at various answers but I can't not find a way to get this going for myself.

I have a function (in node.js) that selects a winner out of a pool, when it selects the winner though, I need it to send a event to the client where it runs a function with data. The data would be the array index of the winner.

Selecting a winner:

```
var endRound = function() {
    ref.child('currentJackpot').once('value', function(data) {
        var currentJackpot = data.val();
        var winnerArray = [];
        var winnerObj = {};
        winnerObj.items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currentJackpot.players.length; i++) {
            winnerObj.items = winnerObj.items.concat(currentJackpot.players[i].items);
            var playerValue = currentJackpot.players[i].itemsValue * 100;
            currentJackpot.players[i].chance = ((currentJackpot.players[i].itemsValue / currentJackpot.jackpotValue) * 100).toFixed(2);
            for (var j = 0; j < playerValue; j++) {
                winnerArray.push(i);
            }
        }
        var formatted = currentJackpot.roundHash.replace(/[.#$/]/g, "");
        sgRef.child(formatted).once('value', function(data) {
            var sgData = data.val();
            salt = sgData.salt;
            rngStr = sgData.rngStr;
            console.log('ROUND ENDED! hash: ', hash, ' salt: ', salt, ' rngStr: ', rngStr);
            currentJackpot.tickets = currentJackpot.jackpotValue * 100;
            currentJackpot.winningTicket = Math.floor((parseFloat(rngStr, 2) * currentJackpot.tickets));
            currentJackpot.winningNumber = (parseFloat(rngStr, 2) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
            currentJackpot.winner = currentJackpot.players[winnerArray[currentJackpot.winningTicket]];
            currentJackpot.salt = salt;
            currentJackpot.rngStr = rngStr;
            winnerObj.jackpotValue = currentJackpot.jackpotValue;
            currentJackpot.jackpotValue = currentJackpot.jackpotValue.toFixed(2);
            winnerObj.winner = currentJackpot.winner;
            winnerObj.tradeToken = currentJackpot.winner.tradeToken;
            ref.child('endedJackpots').push(currentJackpot);
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, data) {
                salt = data;
                rngStr = JSON.stringify(rng());
                bcrypt.hash(rngStr, salt, function(err, data) {
                    hash = data;
                    ref.child('currentJackpot').set({
                        itemsCount: 0,
                        jackpotValue: 0,
                        roundHash: hash,
                    }, function() {
                        console.log('NEW ROUND! hash: ', hash, 'salt: ', salt, 'rngStr: ', rngStr);
                        var formatted = hash.replace(/[.#$/]/g, "");
                        var sgJackpotRef = sgRef.child(formatted);
                        sgRef.set({}, function() {
                            sgJackpotRef.set({
                                salt: salt,
                                rngStr: rngStr,
                            }, function() {
                                request.post({
                                    url: '*******',
                                    body: winnerObj,
                                    json: true,
                                }, function(error, response, body) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        setPollTimer(10000);
                                    } else {
                                        usersRef.child(winnerObj.winner.id).once('value', function(data) {
                                            var userData = data.val();
                                            if (data.child('won').exists()) {
                                                userData.won = (Math.floor(parseFloat(userData.won, 2)) + Math.floor(parseFloat(winnerObj.jackpotValue, 2))).toFixed(2);
                                            } else {
                                                userData.won = (Math.floor(parseFloat(winnerObj.jackpotValue, 2))).toFixed(2);
                                            }
                                            usersRef.child(winnerObj.winner.id).update({
                                                won: userData.won
                                            }, function() {
                                                console.log('Added winnings to user data');
                                            });
                                        });
                                        console.log('Making a withdraw request now to bot');
                                        setPollTimer(10000);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And the function it should run client side:

```
  function slotMachine(winnerIndex) {
    var params = {
      active: 3,
      randomize: function(activeElementIndex){
            return 1;
          }
    };
    var machine = $('.slot').slotMachine( params );

    $("#slotMachineButton").click(function(){
      machine.shuffle(3, function(){
        $(this).text("Index: " + this.active);
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm completely stuck and stressed though, this isn't my code and It's a lot of code I can't grasp where to begin to do this. Any help?

Comment: Have a look at socket.io (simple library that facilitates two way communication between the server and browser). It can be used by the server to sent data to the browser, and the browser can in turn run some javascript upon receiving the data.

Comment: Is your client polling an endpoint for a result, or is your client using sockets and handling them as needed?